# How to access a XAML Resource from a CustomControl.cs C# file?

Tags: wpf, resources, controls

I have a XXXCustomControl.cs class and inside the c# class I want to access via

```
groupStyle.ContainerStyle = this.FindResource("GroupHeaderStyle") as Style;
```

the GroupHeaderStyle, but this style is defined somewhere else (wherever that is...)

Now my question: What is the best place to put my GroupHeaderStyle and how to get it via

FindResource from c# code?

Answer (score 5):

If your Style is defined within a ResourceDictionary you can always access it in code behind with

```
Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/DictionaryName.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
groupStyle.ContainerStyle = resourceDictionary["GroupHeaderStyle"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should include your XAML file containing the style into your App's resource dictionary as MergedDictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--  here you can add some more resources -->
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="mystyles.xaml"/>
            <!--  here you can add some dictionaries -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

See the example here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

Or actually you could put your style definition directly into the App's resources, without merged resource dictionaries. But this way the App's resources usually get bloated quite fast.

Edit:
For the case of library, you don't have an App.xaml available. So you need to do basically the following:

1. Add a resource dictionary to your project, and define the needed styles there.
2. In the control's resources, refer to your dictionary as a merged dictionary.

Note that you need to specify the full path ("[pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)") to the dictionary:

```
<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>
```

Comment: yeah that way I did it with my programm project, but I did not thought that the control project needs/has an app.xaml file. Seems the 3rd party free web custom control project was ripped by the author ROFL :P It seems a custom control library has only a Generic.xaml... So how should I access this generic.xaml from my c# code-behind?

Comment: @Lisa: are you developing a library, not an application?

Comment: Actually YES :-) 10 now... LOL

Comment: @Lisa: added example for libraries.

Comment: Good answer (+1). I added another another way of accessing Styles defined in local or referenced assembly.

Comment: ah btw. lol... a control project does not have a Control.Resources tag as you wrote. A Custom control project just offers me a Generic.xaml file...

Comment: Ray Burns rocked => http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3099362/WPF-Accessing-Resources-Control-Assembly Its the "ComponentResourceKey"

Comment: @Lisa: You can just add this tag, no problem at all.